# display data from mongodb to webpage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRaTJ.png]

I am new in nodejs and want to connect the mongo database using express and nodejs. I want my data show from database to webpage.

///// Model schema///////

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema=mongoose.Schema;

let Data=new Schema({     
    learningEvents:{
        type:String
    },
    learningActivities:{
        type:Array
    },
    indicators:{
        type:Array
    }
});

export default mongoose.model('Data', Data);
```

//////////// complete code of node js/////////////////

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import Data from './models/data';

import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import data from './models/data';

const app=express();
const router=express.Router();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/data');
const connection=mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open',()=>{
    console.log("Mongodb connected successfully");
});

router.route('/').get((req,res)=>{

        res.send('Hello');

    });

router.route('/data').get((req,res)=>{
    Data.find((err,Data)=>{
        if(err)
        console.log(err);
        else
        res.json(Data);

    });
});

app.use('/',router);

app.listen(4000,()=>console.log('Express server is running on port 4000'));
```

Comment: this is not your issue, but if `Data` is your model, then don't have the parameter for the callback also be `Data`. Call it something else not to shadow your model variable.

Answer (score 1):

To display Dynamic data to webpage you would need to use templating engine like ejs handlebars etc. You can not do the same with html for ex:

```js
    blog.find({}, function(err, blogs){
        if(err){
            console.log("An Error Occured");
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.render("index",{blogs: blogs});
        }
    });
```

where index is an ejs file and we pass all the blogs data into it. That can be rendered in the ejs template like

```html
<% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
    <div class = "ui top attached segment">
    <div class = "ui huge header"><%= blog.title %></div>
    <div>
        <div class = "item">
            <img class = "ui centered image"src = "<%= blog.image %>"></img>
        </div>
        <div class = "description">
            <p><%- blog.body.substring(0, 400) %></p>
        </div>
        <a href = "/blogs/<%= blog._id %>">Read More</a>
        <br>
        <div class = "item">
            <span><%= blog.created.toDateString() %></span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        </div>
<% }); %>
```

Link to ejs [Docs](https://ejs.co/#install)

Comment: but i have to read data from mongodb not random data. I mention picture of database.

Comment: you've been given an example, not your exact solution.

Comment: @MatihUllah The code I have mentioned shows you how to dynamically render on the front end. "blogs" is the data that we get when we query for "find" on the mongoose model. In your case you would have to do the same with your "Data"

Comment: I have problem with the mongoose model. How to define model in node js according to the database in above picture

Comment: @MatihUllah Go through this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/